# Pass a reference to a reference

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

I think it's illegal to pass a reference to a reference in C++.However ,when I run this code it gives me no error.

```
void g(int& y)
{
   std::cout << y;
   y++;
 }

 void f(int& x)
{
  g(x);
}
int  main()
{
  int a = 34;
  f(a);
  return 0;

 }
```

Doesn't the formal parameter of
    g()
qualify as a reference to a reference ??

Comment: Er... In your code `g` is declared as `void g(int& y)`. Where do you see "a reference to a reference" in its formal parameter list?

Comment: I was interpreting the     y in g as  int& int & x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) There is nothing wrong with passing a reference to a reference (it is what the move-constructor and move-assignment operators use - though it is actually called a rvalue-reference).

2) What you are doing is not passing a reference to a reference, but rather passing the same reference through `f` to `g`:

```
void g(int& x)
{
    x = 5;
}

void f(int& x)
{
    std::cout << "f-in " << x << std::endl;
    g(x);
    std::cout << "f-out " << x << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 42;
    f(x);
    std::cout << "New x = " << x << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Move constructor and move assignment do not use reference-to-a-reference. The syntax for their argument is `T&&`, but that's **defined** as an rvalue reference. Reference to reference always has been, and continues to be, illegal.

Comment: @PeteBecker:  If you followed his logic, he was assuming that `int&&` was a reference to a reference (and also assuming that chaining 2 functions that both took `int&` as a parameter would be such).  Hence the clarification I placed on #1 followed by further explanation of #2.

Comment: @PeteBecker:  Reading for Comprehension 101 - that is exactly what I said.

Comment: "There is nothing wrong with flying a car, but it's called driving".

Comment: You must be one of those people who reads the specification and gives the client exactly what they said they want instead of what they described wanting ...

Comment: No, I'm one of those people who knows how to write precise, accurate English.

Comment: @PeteBecker:  "**though it is actually called a rvalue-reference**" - I'm not sure how much more precise and accurate you can be there.

Answer (score 6):

No, `g()` is not taking a reference to reference. It takes a reference to an `int`. `f()` forwards the reference to `int` it receives to `g()`.

A "reference to a reference" doesn't actually exist, but there are [**rvalue references**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5591006/315052), which are like references, but allow binding to temporaries.

Answer (score 5):

In the body of `f`, the value of the *expression* `x` is an `int`. The fact that the *variable* `x` has type `int &` means that the value of the expression is an lvalue, and thus it can bind to the parameter of the function `g`.

Answer (score 1):

A reference is an *alias* to a different object. Once the reference has been initialized, it behaves exactly as if you were accessing the object directly, so you are not passing a reference to a reference, but rather a reference to the real object (to which you refer by another reference).

Creating a reference to a reference would be something like:

```
typedef int& intr;
void f(intr& x);    // reference to a reference type
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere in your code you attempt to pass a reference to a reference. Inside `f` expression `x` produces an lvalue of type `int`. It is not a reference. Expressions in C++ never produce accessible results of reference type, since any results of reference type are immediately interpreted by the language as lvalues of non-reference type.

See 5/5

> If an expression initially has the type “reference to T” (8.3.2,
>   8.5.3), the type is adjusted to T prior to any further analysis. The expression designates the object or function denoted by the reference,
>   and the expression is an lvalue or an xvalue, depending on the
>   expression.

P.S. I'm not sure what you mean by "Doesn't the formal parameter of g() qualify as a reference to a reference". The formal parameter of `g` is declared as `int &`. Where do you see "a reference to a reference" here?