# Behaviour of pass by reference and its scope

Tags: c++, c++11

In the below code the variable `a` is passed to a constructor by reference, received by the parameter `x`. Then `x` is passed as a reference to an attribute. The attribute is then initialized with value 3. The program outputs the value 3 when running.

**MY QUESTION**

Shouldn't the program crash or show 2 because after the constructor is called
x should go out of scope and be released and its address should be freed right. and trying to write to it should give a memory access violation. However in this case the x is still in program control holding the address of 'a'

Is this valid c++ behavior or am i missing something?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

class myclass {

public:
    int& attribute;
    myclass(int& x):attribute(x) {

    }

    void func() {
        attribute = 3;
    }
};

int main() {
    int a = 2;
    myclass obj(a);
    obj.func();
    std::cout << a;
    _getch();
}
```

Comment: Initializing a reference from another reference is the same as initializing it from the referred object. A reference is an alias for the referred object in pretty much every sense. Here, `x` *is* `a`.

Comment: Reference members in a class is, more often than not, a code smell - and usually a bug.

Comment: "Shouldn't the program crash" -- You think very highly of Undefined Behavior :-) _Anything_ can happen when you screw up in C++.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass a reference to a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18473496/pass-a-reference-to-a-reference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior of the program line by line

variable "a" is initialized with value 2

```
int a = 2;
```

Initialize `obj` with the variable `a`

```
myclass obj(a);
```

First `x` becomes the reference to `a`, then `attribute` becomes the reference to `x`. Consequently, `attribute` becomes the reference to `a`, which has the value 2 at the moment.

```
myclass(int& x):attribute(x) {}
```

Call `func()` of `obj`

```
obj.func();
```

`attribute` is the reference to `a`. 
Both "attribute" and "a" are changed to 3. Consider them as the same, 
single variable, just with difference alias. 
That means, at this moment, `attribute` and `a` refers to the same variable, 
and can be used interchangeably.

```
void func() {
    attribute = 3;  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Just joins SO, getting used to the editor

Comment: Replaced code comment by plain text, as commented above

Answer (score 5):

No this program is fine. `attribute` is a reference to `a`. The fact that `x` has gone out of scope is neither here nor there.

If you changed your code to

```
myclass(int x):attribute(x)
```

then that would be a problem.