# C++ rvalue and pointer of pointer when should I use it?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Please consider these 2 lines of code

```
void doStuff(int ** i)
void doStuff2( int && i)
```

in the first one I assume that it is a pointer of pointer and the second is an rvalue, 
I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590978/reference-of-reference-in-c) and it explains the rvalue but when should I use the first and when should I use the second ?

could you clarify this to me please ?

Comment: `&&` is NOT a reference of reference, but a rvalue reference.

Comment: The second is not a "reference of reference" (no such thing), it's an rvalue reference. Its usage requires a full essay.

Comment: thanks gays for correcting me I've edited the question but still need an answer.

Comment: The pointer of pointer is something one would hardly use often in C++, due to the prevalence of references, smart pointers and containers. I find it mostly useful in traversing old-school singly-linked lists.

Comment: Comparing rvalue reference and pointer to pointer is pointless. They are completely different things.

Comment: @YuHao yes true, but I'm asking **when** to use these

Comment: @RiadhHAJAMOR - IMO you shouldn't really use `**` in C++, unless you are dealing with an old C API, as for `&&` - that's mostly used in the context of move semantics.

Comment: @Medinoc so I shouldn't  use this ? what  about the second ?

Comment: You should definitely use the second in contexts where it's relevant: Implementing *move semantics* in your objects, and using it where it's important to avoid a copy.

Comment: Medinoc, @ddriver thank you for helping me understand it

Comment: @RiadhHAJAMOR you aren't understanding the comments. These two things have *nothing to do with each other*. They don't mean anything even remotely similar. The question of "when" to use one or the other is meaningless: it's like asking for the "difference" between `while` and `class`. Your edit just makes the question even less clear since it hides the fact that it was originally based on the mistaken idea that reference-to-reference was something that existed in C++.

Comment: Yes obviously I had a confusion between those concepts and thought that they are for pointer/arrays manipulation, I had specified in my post that I'm truly a beginner in c++ but this phrase was removed by the first editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int ** i` **is a pointer to a pointer.**

Generally, use this sparingly, as this may have different meanings and you have better ways to express that in C++.

It may be a pointer to single variable containing a pointer to a single int:

```
int value = 0;
int * pValue = &value;
int ** ppValue = &pValue;
```

However, each may also be a pointer to the first element of an array:

```
int valuesA[1000], valuesB[100], valuesC[10];
int * pValues[] = { valuesA, valuesB, valuesC };
   // these are actually pointers to the first element of the array
int ** ppValues = pValues;
```

Use this *only* with clear documentation how to access elements, how to know the element sizes, and who is responsible for freeing (if any), how long the pointers are valid etc.

Usually, if you have such an array / matrix, you certainly should wrap it behind a safe-to-use interface, or replace it alltogether e.g. with a `vector<vector<int>>`.

Even for the single-int use cases there are usually better options. E.g. a function signature that allows to modify a pointer, a reference to a pointer would be more suitable:

```
bool SelectValue(int *& p) { ... }
```

int && **is a rvalue reference**.

Unlike the `int **`, this is *not* a double indirection.

It is, roughly a reference that can also bind to a temporary value.
("Normal" references cannot).

[A Brief Introduction to Rvalue References](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/rvalue.html)